# Existe diferença entre "Equipe de Testes" e "Equipe de QA"?

Tags: testes

Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre testes.

Ouvi algumas vezes pessoas falando *...a equipe de QA (Quality Assurance)...*

Até onde sei, *QA* é um ambiente e não uma equipe. Por isso não entendi.

---

As dúvidas são:

- Está certo falar *Equipe de QA*?
- Existe alguma diferença entre *Equipe de Testes* e *Equipe de QA*?
- Se existem diferenças, quais são?

Comment: O QA – Quality Assurance – Define-se como um conjunto de atividades para **garantir a qualidade** nos processos de desenvolvimento - [Fonte](https://targettrust.com.br/blog/diferenca-de-qa-para-qc/)

Comment: @Everson _Define-se como um conjunto de atividades_, então não deve-se chamar uma equipe de QA, certo?

Comment: O que querem dizer é: Existe uma equipa de testes para cada ambiente, por norma DEV(desenvolvimento) é efetuado pela equipa que desenvolve, SIT (Testes Integrados) são realizados pela equipa de "testes", e por fim existe a equipa de testes de QUA (Qualidade)

Comment: QA vai analisar vários pontos além do simples teste. Tá bonito? Boa ux? Divertido de usar? Intuitivo? O que posso fazer com esse _crap_ entregue pelo time de desenvolvimento para ficar mais palatável? O manual está fácil de ler? Os botões estão com nomes/ícones confusos?

Comment: Boa, @JeffersonQuesado você pode responder, por favor? Aí coloca também as responsabilidades da equipe de testes, por favor :)

Answer (score 0):

Analista de Qualidade é um profissional da área de SQA, já o Analista de Teste é um profissional da área de Teste de Software.

O QAI faz essa diferenciação, tanto que há a Certified Software Quality Analyst (CSQA), para profissionais de SQA e a Certified Software Tester (CSTE), para profissionais de Teste de Software.

Resumindo, as atividades de uma Analista de Qualidade são diferentes da do Analista de Teste, portanto são cargos diferentes, embora seja comum a sobreposição de funções em muitas empresas.

Comment: Legal! O que cada um faz que os diferencia?

Comment: Analista de Teste: Valida o produto

Analista de Qualidade: Valida todo o processo que envolve a criação do produto

Answer (score -5):

```
WM R:- O que menos o pessoal da área de Q.A. e Testes de Software faz ou sabe que precisa fazer é ESTUDAR, LER, em sua profissão, nossa área já existe um vasto material disponível em diversos formatos.
WM R:- Mas eu trago parte de um resumo didático, esclareçamos inicialmente ... Testes de Software nasceu de dentro do Desenvolvimento, por pessoas que começaram a desempenhar atividades que os desenvolvedores odiavam fazer, assim foram surgindo os Testadores sendo que o único teste que ficou de início com os desenvolvedores foram os UNITÁRIOS (por carência técnica imediata de técnica).
WM R:- Depois de muitos anos rolando assim, veio o Sr. Glenford J. Myers  (considerado patrono dos Testes de Software) juntando seu artigos técnicos e de consultoria, lançando o livro " The Art of Software Testing ", desde esta data de publicação do livro " 20 de Fevereiro de 1979 " comemora-se internacionalmente o dia do Teste de Software.
WM R:- Notem que o que descrevi acima, trata-se de Testes de Software, não escrevi um " A " sobre Q.A. que faço agora, pra começar, afirmo-lhes que Testes de Software se trata de uma FERRAMENTA dentro de Q.A. pertence a disciplina de Q.A. , ferramenta como atividade que profissionais envolvidos com desenvolvimento podem estabelecer Q.A. ou S.Q.A. (Quality Assurance ou Software Quality Assurance).
WM R:- Então desmistifico que Q.A. não é um ambiente! , Q.A. está para nós como uma "Disciplina mental baseada em esforços e medida por complexidade e Risco"(Walter Melo), onde para alguns projetos designa-se os testes de Software para alcançar a qualidade almejada colocada como meta.
WM R:- Se quem estiver lendo atue em nossa área, pouco tempo, muito tempo ou perguntem para quem já seja da área se não fizerem parte, vão entender que "Requisitos, Use cases, histórias e afins", muitas vezes não são apresentados com Completude, sem ambiguidade, cem critérios de entrada e saída ... e pouca gente conhece, conseguem implementar um processo robusto, mas isso é função de um profissional de Q.A. validar! 
WM R:- a Validação de integridade entre ambientes, equidade e geração de dados é função de um profissional de Q.A.(já foi chamado de arquiteto.
WM R:- Validar os testes e evidências de unitários para entrada nos primeiros testes da área de Testes é função de um profissional de Q.A.
WM R:- Acompanhar/suportar os UATs (User Acceptance Tests) é função de um profissional de Q.A.
WM R:- Logo , como estas são apenas algumas funções tb de Q.A., você terá um time de chamados Q.A.s , responsáveis por estas e muitas outras atividades que se reúnem, Têm liderança, estão abaixo de gerência..., logo são um TIME ! a chamada EQUIPE DE Q.A.! assim como temos EQUIPE DE TESTES!, resumindo ... se existe diferença entre as duas, claro, uma pertence a outra, está contida, é uma ferramenta da outra e possuem escopos muito diferentes de atuação !!!!!!
WM R:- Minha dica, não adianta só saber apertar botões e testar APIs, sistemas web, mobile, pois estará fadado a trabalhar assim e depois de um tempo não terá mais atividade, ESTUDE... ESTude , estude..... nunca é demais, tem sempre mais a aprender e não deixe de conhecer de onde veio pra onde vai e se tudo ok!
```

Comment: Evite cumprimentos, apresentações, agradecimentos e qualquer interação não técnica. Também veja [answer] e entenda que o Stack Overflow [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos [um site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387).